# Eclipse saying selection does not contain a main type?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not sure why it's saying that when I have a main? I'm not sure what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
public class Feet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s|%-15s%-15s\n","Feet","Meters","Meters","Feet");
        System.out.println( String.format("%62s"," ").replace(' ', '-') );

        for (int m = 20, f = 1  ; f <=10; f++, m+=5) {
            System.out.printf("%-15.1f%-15.3f | %-15.1f%-15.3f\n", (float) f, footToMeter (f), (float) m, meterToFoot (m));
        }
    }

    /** Convert from meter to foot */
    public static double meterToFoot(double meter) {
        return 3.279 * meter;
    }

    /** Convert from foot to meter */
    public static double footToMeter(double foot) {
        return  0.305 * foot;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. Using eclipse and it compiles. Try to right click your file and choose `Run As > Java Application`

Comment: How you are running this class ?

Comment: I am running it as a Java Application.

Comment: @Nadia did you right click it and chose "run as -> Java Application"?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm not sure why it's saying that when the code works on an online compiler.

Comment: Is it in a `Source Folder` of a proper `Java Project` as you would create using the **New Java Project** wizard? Otherwise it has no idea what classpath to set up for the runtime it has to launch, including what to treat as the main class.

Comment: I'm not sure, I just imported it from textedit. How do I make for sure it is in a source folder?

Comment: @Nadia http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_create_java_project.htm Also read the next 2 sites of that tutorial (Packages being the less important) And make sure your source file is in the `src` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the folder where you put your main class then click on

> Build Path --> Use as Source Folder

. Finally run your main file as java application. Hope this problem will be solved.